# Is the difference between Medial v.s. Lateral Patellofemoral Pain Syndrome (PFPS) documented?

Tags: pain, physical-therapy

I haven't been able to find any discussion on the difference between medial v.s. lateral PFPS.  I have seen a lot of information about strengthening external hip rotators and hip abductors being a successful treatment, but this seems like it's targeting lateral PFPS. Instead medial PFPS should be targeted by training internal hip rotators.

My reasoning is that stronger internal rotators would align the patellofemoral with a more inwards rotation during knee flexion.  This way, the rectus femorous will pull in a direction which takes pressure off the medial side of the grove.

What is the reasoning behind targeting the external structures rather than the medial/internal structures in medial PFPS?